# Mysql replace using regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have a query like the following

```
SELECT FIELDATA FROM DATASET WHERE CATID = 2;
```

Output is

```
21@Marketing;76@Sales
```

The output can also be the following in case the database does not have multiple values stored.

```
21@Marketing
```

I tried the following

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -1) AS FIELDATA FROM DATASET WHERE CATID = 2;
```

but it did not give the desired result.

Is it possible to do string manipulation so that the output becomes 
**Marketing, Sales** in the former and just **Marketing** in the latter.

To summarise The pattern of input

```
 number1@text1;number2@text2;number3@text;
```

and the output should be

```
 text1, text2, text3
```

Comment: Nope you can't that's a feature request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql#comment33803643_986826

Comment: Do not put lists into a column.  If you do, then leave tasks like this to the app.

Comment: Why so Rick James? Any reasoning behind your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there is no easy way to match your expectation based on current MySQL functions.

Here is a brute solution to match your expectation, based on separator of "@" and ";".

Sample SQL:

```
-- data
CREATE TABLE test.DATASET ( ID INT NOT NULL, U_NAME VARCHAR(45) NULL, FIELDATA VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)); 
INSERT INTO test.DATASET (ID, U_NAME, FIELDATA) VALUES ('1', 'ALPHA', '21@Marketing;31@Sales'); 
INSERT INTO test.DATASET (ID, U_NAME, FIELDATA) VALUES ('2', 'BETA', '21@Marketing');

-- Query wanted, which can handle up to 5 secsions
SELECT 
    FIELDATA, 
    CONCAT_WS(
        ', ',
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -5), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -4), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -3), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -2), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -1), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp)
    ) output
FROM  test.DATASET JOIN (SELECT @tmp := NULL) v;
```

-- Query wanted, which can handle up to 2 secsions
SELECT 
    FIELDATA, 
    CONCAT_WS(
        ', ', 
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -2), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp), 
        IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -1), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp) 
        ) output 
FROM test.DATASET JOIN (SELECT @tmp := NULL) v;

Output:

```
mysql> -- Query wanted, which can handle up to 5 secsions
mysql> SELECT
    ->     FIELDATA,
    ->     CONCAT_WS(
    ->         ', ',
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -5), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -4), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -3), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -2), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -1), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp)
    ->     ) output
    -> FROM  test.DATASET JOIN (SELECT @tmp := NULL) v;
+-----------------------+------------------+
| FIELDATA              | output           |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| 21@Marketing;31@Sales | Marketing, Sales |
| 21@Marketing          | Marketing        |
+-----------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- Query wanted, which can handle up to 2 secsions
mysql> SELECT
    ->     FIELDATA,
    ->     CONCAT_WS(
    ->         ', ',
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -2), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
    ->         IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -1), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp)
    ->         ) output
    -> FROM test.DATASET JOIN (SELECT @tmp := NULL) v;
+-----------------------+------------------+
| FIELDATA              | output           |
+-----------------------+------------------+
| 21@Marketing;31@Sales | Marketing, Sales |
| 21@Marketing          | Marketing        |
+-----------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I am trying to run the query and its just not coming well for me.

Comment: SELECT FIELDATA, CONCAT_WS(
             ', ',
             IF((FIELDATA=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str, '@', -5), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, FIELDATA)
         ) output  FROM DATASET WHERE CATID = 2;

Comment: the output is the same as column value

Comment: pls provide some of your sample data.

Comment: My bad. Just replace "@str" with your column name to use in your query.

The variable @tmp should be kept. If you want to keey only one IF to match one @, keep the last one , the '-1' one.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `test`.`DATASET` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `U_NAME` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `FIELDATA` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));

Comment: Data: INSERT INTO `test`.`DATASET` (`ID`, `U_NAME`, `FIELDATA`) VALUES ('1', 'ALPHA', '21@Marketing;31@Sales');
INSERT INTO `test`.`DATASET` (`ID`, `U_NAME`, `FIELDATA`) VALUES ('2', 'BETA', '21@Marketing');

Comment: I ran the following query: SELECT
       FIELDATA,  CONCAT_WS(
             ', ',
   IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -5), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp),
   IF((@tmp:=SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(FIELDATA, '@', -4), ';', 1)) LIKE '%@%', NULL, @tmp)                     
         ) output FROM test.DATASET ;

Comment: And I could not find any output.

Comment: Please check the updated post. I verified with data you post in comments.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, It is giving me results. Although I have one questions why do we need to use the JOIN ? "JOIN (SELECT @tmp := NULL) v" as without join I am getting the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my tentative on your problem. I've found some functions on the web (I'll put the credits later) and have combined them to make it work for your specific need: you need to get a clean string with 2 levels of delimiters (@ and ;).

See below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION splitter(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION substrCount(s VARCHAR(255), ss VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS tinyint(3) unsigned
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE count TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE offset TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET s = NULL;
  SET count = 0;
  SET offset = 1;
  REPEAT
    IF NOT ISNULL(s) AND offset > 0 THEN
      SET offset = LOCATE(ss, s, offset);
      IF offset > 0 THEN
        SET count = count + 1;
        SET offset = offset + 1;
      END IF;
    END IF;
   UNTIL ISNULL(s) OR offset = 0 END REPEAT;
   RETURN count;
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION split_str(x varchar(255), delim varchar(12), delim2 varchar(12), return_separator varchar(12)) RETURNS varchar(255)
BEGIN
  SET @Valcount = substrCount(x,delim)+1;
  SET @v1=0;
  SET @v2='';
  WHILE (@v1 < @Valcount) DO
    set @val = splitter(x,delim,@v1+1);
    if @v1 = 0 then
      SET @v2 = world.split_str(@val,delim2,2);
    else
      SET @v2 = concat(@v2,return_separator,world.split_str(@val,delim2,2));
    end if;
    SET @v1 = @v1 + 1;
  END WHILE;
  return @v2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then, you can use it like below, assuming that you have a table t2 with a field f2 that contains your sample string "number1@text1;number2@text2;number3@text;":

```
select split_str(f2,';','@',', '), f2 from t2
```

The result will be:

```
text1, text2, text
```

As promissed, the authors:

Function substrCount created by [Andrew Hanna on August 24 2006 8:04pm](http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function)

Function splitter created by [Federico Cargnelutti on 2009](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Function split_str created by [mtlseo on 2012](http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function/)

Comment: Thanks Walter.. Never done functions before. Where do I place the function during run time?

Comment: You can simply run the creation script  once in your database and then use like in the example: select split_str(f2,';','@',', '), f2 from t2

Comment: Thats cool. Would it be as easy to create and use in AWS RDS as well?

Comment: Yes, you can use there.

Comment: This solution also works well, but for easier roll out I used Dylan Su's answer. Since it has been tested and used, I chose Dylan Su's one as accepted answer. But I would have to really appreciate Walter_Ritzel answer which is generic can be used across the places. I will be eventually using this solution.

Comment: It is ok. But mine was tested and used by many people as well (just not by me), as this is the solution recommended in any MySQL forum until MySQL implements the regex_replace native.